# CVS to SVN one branch at a time

Tags: svn, migration, cvs

Is it possible to transfer a repository from CVS to SVN one branch/tag at a time?

Because each branch is currently a different project, I would like to be able to transfer the branches one at a time (when there is little activity on a specific branch).
Eventually the branches will all exist in the same svn repository.

Comment: Can you explain the migration plan a bit? Do you want to split up the branches into different SVN repositories?

Answer (score 1):

The approach to migrate from CVS to SVN is to use the [cvs2svn](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org) tool. This migration tool assumes a one time action to convert the CVS repository to SVN. You can apply various transformations, as [documented](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html). During the conversion the CVS repository should be frozen, and after which everybody should use the SVN repository. The tool isn't suited for gradually moving parts of the CVS to the SVN. It doesn't create a persistent record of which CVS version relates to which SVN revision number. Thus if you would convert only parts of the CVS at the time you will lose branching information. So it's really best to convert all at once. Note, you can convert [one CVS module at the time](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#oneatatime). That's because CVS modules stand on their own.